# Referencing some input fields submitted in a form to filter them on PHP

Tags: php, forms, post, input, foreach

I have a series of form input fields that are posted in a PHP code.

However, I would like to use a foreach to POST only some of the fields, not all of them. Would there be any way to give a different reference to some of the inputs sent in the form so when I execute my code below only some POSTS are taken into account and others are skipped?

PHP:

```
foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) 
    {
    $k=htmlspecialchars($key);
    $v=htmlspecialchars($value);
    if(in_array($k, $possible)) {
    $query2 .= $k." = ?";
    $values[]=$v;  //append values to an array for later use
    if($i < ($len-2)) $query2 .= ', ';
    $i++;
}
```

FORM:
input1
input2
input3
input4

I would like to use only input1, 3 and 4 for my foreach.

Thanks!

Comment: Define `$possible`. :-)

Comment: Put your $_POST info into an array, leaving out the one you dont want, then process the array the same way.

Comment: I answered, then realized that @MartyMcVry is right. You already have the functionality written, you just need all the accepted post names to be added to that array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) 
{
  $k=htmlspecialchars($key);
  $v=htmlspecialchars($value);
  if($k=='input2'){continue;}
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could unset some POST parameters, if you have certain that you will not need them.

```
$var = $_POST['input2'];
unset($_POST['input2']);
foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) 
{ 
    ...//rest of code here
}
```

Comment: altering the POST and GET arrays will come back to haunt you because a little script you write for some quick little project gets pulled into a bigger project and then 2 or 3 years later your stuck with it.